# Supervisor's feelings toward publishing prior work without him

Tags: publications, advisor

Before starting my Ph.D at university X, I had a research stay in university Y. I submitted a paper related to my work done at university Y and it took 2 years to be published. At the time of publication I was a Ph.D student at university X, but I did not tell my supervisor about the submitted paper, because it was related to my previous work which was not related to my Ph.D. I am afraid about my supervisor's feelings. Will this publication make him upset?

Comment: Two points of clarification would help us answer this: how closely related is the prior paper to your current field (e.g. Chemistry vs. Computer Science, or algorithms vs. AI?)? And, if you have seen your advisor get upset about other things, what are the circumstances that made him upset in the past?

Comment: my works done for might be related for instance in quantum physics vs nuclear physics. Nothing special happened . I just feel that he get upset? Should I ask him directly bout this issue?

Comment: Recently I asked him to submit a prepared paper jointly, but he has not replied me about its submission yet?

Comment: (1) As for many similar questions, go talk to them. (2) work done under/with somebody else before arriving at X is not 'controlled' by your current advisor, but they should have been told that 'Hey, I'm getting a paper out of my previous work'. You affiliation for that work is Y with a note that you are now at X.

Comment: @JonCuster, thank you for your comment. As my paper has been published, so it is not possible to add a note the I am now at X. Is it a bad situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any work you did at a prior institution—particularly something you did before starting a PhD in a different field—before joining your present institution is not really any of your current advisor's concern, *unless* working on it involved a significant distraction from your assigned work. (That is, he was paying you to work on project A, and you spent all your time working for project B.) It doesn't sound like this is the case, so I wouldn't lose any sleep over this.

Comment: Agreed; if you do need to dedicate some time to wrap up the previous paper that shouldn't really be a problem either, but let your current advisor know/ask permission: "I got reviews back from a paper I submitted when I was working with Dr. Otherguy, and I need a week to write a response and revise the paper. Is that okay?" Honestly, if your advisor can't get on board with a request like that they are a terrible academic.